When installing prowler: "site-packages is not writeable"
I wan to install Prowler on my windows but getting following error when running command:
pip install prowler

Error:

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

I am using Python version 3.12.2
Please suggest how to rectify this error?
I tried python3 -m pip install prowler but same error kept on coming.
